# py2exe with matplotlib, numpy and pylab

Tags: python, py2exe, matplotlib

I'm trying to generate an executable. the packages I am using are

```
import sys
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pylab import *
from numpy import *
```

the setup.py is the following

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
import matplotlib

setup(console=['<python file>'],data_files=matplotlib.get_py2exe_datafiles(),)
```

but I get an error related to pyplot.pyc

> Import Error: no module named backend_tkagg

any way around to fix it?

Comment: The py2exe wiki has a page all about getting matplotlib and py2exe working.  See http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/MatPlotLib

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should include the matplotlib module explicitly.
If you do that you can get some errors from unavailable dlls, so then you should exclude them.
A setup that works for me with your file:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
import matplotlib

setup(console=['afile.py'],
      options={
               'py2exe': {
                          'packages' :  ['matplotlib', 'pytz'],
                          'dll_excludes': ['libgdk-win32-2.0-0.dll',
                                         'libgobject-2.0-0.dll',
                                         'libgdk_pixbuf-2.0-0.dll',
                                         'libgtk-win32-2.0-0.dll',
                                         'libglib-2.0-0.dll',
                                         'libcairo-2.dll',
                                         'libpango-1.0-0.dll',
                                         'libpangowin32-1.0-0.dll',
                                         'libpangocairo-1.0-0.dll',
                                         'libglade-2.0-0.dll',
                                         'libgmodule-2.0-0.dll',
                                         'libgthread-2.0-0.dll',
                                         'QtGui4.dll', 'QtCore.dll',
                                         'QtCore4.dll'
                                        ],
                          }
                },
      data_files=matplotlib.get_py2exe_datafiles(),)
```

Comment: In order to get this to work, I had to add `'excludes':['zmq']` to the above script. Otherwise I'd get a "failed to find libzmq.pyd" when running executing my setup script.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to add (python2.7):

```
    import sys
    sys.path.append("C:\\pathToYourPython\\pythonxy2731\\console\\Microsoft.VC90.CRT")
```