# EXE with MatplotLib Crashes

Tags: python, matplotlib, py2exe

I'm developing an application using Python 3.4 and PyQt4 with LiClipse as the IDE and have an issue with plotting graphs closing the entire program with no error after I've compiled the program into an executable.  I've pin-pointed the problem area and know that calling matplotlib.figure.Figure() is the crash culprit but I don't know where to go from here.

```
import matplotlib
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
class GraphWidget(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self,parent=None,width = 500, height = 600, dpi = 100):

        self.width = width/dpi
        self.height = height/dpi
        self.dpi = dpi

        #================crashes here=============#
        self.figure = Figure((self.width,self.height), dpi=self.dpi)
        #=========================================#

        alert = QMessageBox()
        alert.setText("Passed Figure()")
        alert.exec_()

        FigureCanvas.__init__(self,self.figure)
        alert = QMessageBox()
        alert.setText("Passed super init")
        alert.exec_()

        self.canvas = self
        self.axis = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding,QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.parent = parent

    def set_new_graph(self,data,labels):
        self.layoutVert = QVBoxLayout(self)
        size = QSize(self.width*self.dpi,self.height*self.dpi)

        self.axis.hold(False)

        mined = min(data.totalamount) - round(min(data.totalamount)*.1,0)
        if mined > 0: mined = 0
        maxed = max(data.totalamount) + round(max(data.totalamount)*.1,0)
        if maxed == mined: maxed += 5 

        data.plot(x = data.totalamount
                  , ax = self.axis
                  , kind = 'bar'
                  , rot=0
                  , legend = False
                  , sharex = True
                  , sharey = True
#                 , xticks = labels
                  , ylim = (mined,maxed)
                  , table = False)
#         self.axis.set_ylim(mined,maxed)
        self.axis.set_xticklabels(labels, fontsize = 'small')

        self.axis.set_title("Sales History over Past Year")
        self.canvas.draw()
        self.resize(size)
        self.layoutVert.addWidget(self.canvas)
```

My py2exe setup script produces a usable executable for all functions except when a graph is initialized on the page:

```
mpld = matplotlib.get_py2exe_datafiles()
include = ['sip','pandas','reportlab'
         , 'PyQt4'
         , 'PyQt4.QtGui'
         , 'PyQt4.QtCore'
         , 'PyQt4.Qt'
         ,'reportlab.rl_settings','scipy','win32com'
         ,'win32com.client'
         , 'matplotlib'
         , 'matplotlib.backends'
         , 'matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg'
         , 'matplotlib.figure'
         ]

exclude = ['nbformat','win32com.gen_py',"six.moves.urllib.parse",
    '_gtkagg', '_tkagg', '_agg2', 
    '_cairo', '_cocoaagg',
    '_fltkagg', '_gtk', '_gtkcairo']

setup(name="ServiceMgmt",
        # console based executables
        console=[],

        # windows subsystem executables (no console)
        windows=['ServiceMgmt.py'],

        # py2exe options
        #zipfile=None,
        options={"py2exe": py2exe_options},
        data_files=mpld
        )
```

I am able to run all other functions of my application in the executable but without issue.  No visible error is shown, and the application works fine prior to compiling.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: A [mcve] would be useful. For instance, the whole setup.py would tell if `data_files=matplotlib.get_py2exe_datafiles()` is present as in [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11062854/5781248)

Comment: @J.J.Hakala, I've updated the setup script.  I do use data_files=matplotlib.get_py2exe_datafiles()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My troubleshooting found numpy.core to be the culprit of my issue.  I re-installed numpy and the executable runs properly now.